# Jest & RN & Realm : Error: Cannot find module 'throwOnWrongReactAPI' from 'react-native.js

Tags: react-native, realm, jestjs

I'm using `jest` for unit testing in a `react native` app, which usually works fine.

Trying to use `realm` breaks the tests and gives this error:

```
 Runtime Error
  - Error: Cannot find module 'throwOnWrongReactAPI' from 'react-native.js'
        at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:197:17)
        at Runtime._resolveModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:304:32)
        at Runtime._getNormalizedModuleID (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:465:31)
        at Runtime._shouldMock (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:511:27)
        at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:263:14)
        at eval (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:178:32)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:185:492)
        at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:352:17)
        at Runtime.requireModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:202:14)
        at Runtime._generateMock (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:418:34)
1 test suite failed, 0 tests passed (0 total in 1 test suite, run time 6.482s)
```

This is the test file:

```
jest.unmock('../classes/feed.js');
import Feed from '../classes/feed';

describe('Feed class', () => {
  it('returns [1, 2] when calling _slice([0, 1, 2], 1)', () => {
    expect(Feed._slice([0, 1, 2], 1)).toEqual([1, 2]);
  });
});
```

This is the file `../classes/feed.js`:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class Feed {
  _slice(a, b) {
    return [1, 2];
  }
};

export default new Feed();
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
  "flux": "^2.1.1",
  "react": "^15.1",
  "react-native": "^0.28",
  "react-native-collapsible": "^0.6.0",
  "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.2.1",
  "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "git+https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view.git",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.2",
  "realm": "^0.13.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
  "babel-jest": "^13.0.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "jest-cli": "^13.0.0"
},
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true
  }
}
```

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

The fact that `throwOnWrongReactAPI` is called, indicates that there is a deprecated usage of the module `react` (see [RN v0.25.1 release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1)), but the stacktrace doesn't help and I *did* fix this in the past.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by runnung `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react-native` and changing the `.babelrc` to

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```